# django rest API development Using Swagger UI, got"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: python, django, rest, django-authentication, swagger

Currently involving in a django-based project, working on rest API development. Using `Swagger` for tracking docs. Everything went well until today. Today I tried to add some testcase for endpoints. In order to make test work, for some reason, I need to set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` and remove `allauth.socialaccount` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings. But after that the response code return 403 when I tried to use `Swagger` for tracking every endpoints in API.

Here is the response body:

```
{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}.
```

What I have done to try to fix this issue is set back settings. But still return the same response code and response body.

Anyone have any ideas about this issue? Super weird since it should work when setting back all settings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the response and the information you have provided, I assume your api views require authentication. You can provide an api key to swagger in your `settings.py` as documented [here](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) under the 'Configuration' header